# Replace values in one vector based on values greater than x in separate vector of dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement, replace

I have a dataframe where values above certain level in one vector should be changed in next vector.

I have tried if function, which gives back 'NA'.

```
if (mydata$duration >15) {
mydata$code==3
}
```

Here's some code of what the end function should look like labelled 'recode'

```
duration<-c(1,14,5,17,9,10,14,16,2,8,3,18)
code<-c(1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2)
mydata<-data.frame(code,duration)
recode<-c(1,2,1,3,1,2,1,3,1,2,1,3)
mydata<-data.frame(recode,duration)
```

Comment: have you looked at the [`ifelse`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/ifelse.html) function? `ifelse(duration > 15, 3, code)`

Comment: Hi @bouncy I don't think that ifelse works for vectors that already exist, and the 1,2 code is predefined to those numbers.

Comment: `mydata$code <- with(mydata, replace(code, duration > 15, 3))`

Comment: Did you try the code I sent? `ifelse` most certainly does work for vectors that already exist

Comment: Thank you @bouncyball apologies, your code worked great

Comment: Thank you @Uwe your code also worked great

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either the 'ifelse' or the 'with (replace)' function worked well.

```
mydata$code<-ifelse(mydata$duration>15,3,mydata$code)

mydata$code<-with(mydata,replace(code,duration>15,3))
```